# How to change visual state of stackpanel from a keyboard event

Tags: c++-winrt

In a C++/winrt app I am able to handle a click in a stackpanel and respond by changing the background of the panel. But if I call the same method from the KeyDown event handler for the main page the appearance of the panel does not change. Both calls to the panel's background change are happening on one of the SHCore.dll threads, and I wonder why they are not on the "Main Thread." Using the dispatcher as follows still leaves me on the SHCore thread:

```
Window::Current().Dispatcher().RunAsync(Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcherPriority::High, [this, theKey,&handled]
                        {
                        handled = PressLetterKey(theKey);

                        });
```

As there is no visible effect from triggering the change within the keydown handler I begin to wonder if this is a thread issue. Yet the thread does appear to the same one in both the functional and the non-functional cases, and both the clickhandler and the keydown handler are calling the same method on the stackpanel - Could the thread here be the problem, or is there some other reason why the panel does not show its change in appearance when triggered by a keydown?

The triggering doesn't have to be a keydown, of course - I'm really just asking if the stackpanel's appearance can be toggled programmatically...for instance if one wanted to blink a button.

Answer (score 0):

OK, once again I've just made a dumb error, but what can be salvaged here is an answer to the threading question. Yes, the SHCore thread is the UIThread, at least here. The "Main Thread" is something else. Any click event or keydown event arrives on the UI thread ready for action, there's no need to call dispatcher. In my case, I was triggering changes in one of a large series of stack panels and - the one I thought I was triggering was actually not the correct one; the triggered item was simply offscreen... so there you have it!